# How to use RangeSlider not cross each

Tags: android, rangeslider

I use material design components `RangeSlider`

And I want to do is when left (or right)slider touch another slider, it should not over it

I have no idea how to do it. Or exists any api that can easily achieve?

[image]

Comment: It is fixed with https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/71fcb73c7ff52da799f578fd895041fc69372d54

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti  Thanks. I read the doc but don't know how to use it

Comment: You have only to wait for the next release where the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent crossing each other is the standard behavior [starting from](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/e5430f9488a0773f413af7b3d7d9cb540ee478f5) the version **`1.2.0-rc01`** and **`1.3.0-alpha02`**,

Use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-rc01'
```

or higher versions.

*Note:* The `1.2.0-rc01` is newer than `1.3.0-alpha01` (which is not fixed yet).

Comment: I amusinf 1.3.0alpha1 still I have same problem rangeslider crossing each other

Comment: @sarwadnyadeshpande The `1.2.0-rc01` is newer than `1.3.0-alpha01`. This fix is not merged yet in the 1.3.0 (only snapshot releases).